# A box has a capacity for 10 pieces of candy , if there are 4 kinds of candy , how many ways can the box be filled?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> A box has a capacity for 10 pieces of candy , if there are 4 kinds of candy , how many ways can the box be filled ?

My try :-

$x+y+z+k=10$    , by **Stars and Bars**

$^{(10+4-1)}C_{10} =^{(10+4-1)}C_3  = ^{13}C_3$

Is my approach right ?

Thank you

Comment: Stars and bars is the correct approach.

Comment: I will point out that nowhere does it say that the box must be completely filled.  You should change your $=$ to a $\leq$ and make the appropriate change to the resulting formula to account for that.

Comment: We can also consider that the box may contain only 3 kind of candies

Comment: FYI, the case mentioned by JMoravitz is most easily handled by adding a 5th "type" of candy that represents the absence of a candy.

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty what are you talking about?  The stars and bars approach already handles the possibility of a single type of candy appearing in the box, three kinds of candy appearing in the box, or any other arrangement...

Comment: @JMoravitz I am considering there is only 3 types of candies then we cannot use Star and Bars

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty you either do not understand the problem, you do not understand the stars-and-bars method, or you do not understand the words you are saying... in whatever the case you are not making any sense.